# sbt/sbt : no such file or directory error

Tags: scala, sbt, apache-spark, ubuntu-14.10

I'm trying to install spark in my ubuntu machine. I have installed sbt and scala. I'm able to view their versions. But, when I try to install spark using 'sbt/sbt assembly' command, i get the below error.
'bash: sbt/sbt: No such file or directory'

Can you please let me know where I am making a mistake. I have been stuck here since yesterday.

Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: What do you mean? Installing spark is done by unzipping to a folder? Are you trying to build spark?  Maybe building a spark app? More info is needed

Comment: Yes, building the spark. sorry for the confusion. Issue is fixed. Thank you for your response

Comment: how did you solve it

Comment: @SSD0113 How did you fix this? I am facing the same issue, trying to run *stn/stb assembly* on spark 2.1.1

Answer (score 4):

You may had downloaded the pre-built version of Spark. If its a pre-built you dont need to execute built tool command(sbt) and it wont be available.

Comment: That may be the problem. I have figured out the way to build it. I will post in the answer. Thank you for your response. :)

Comment: @SSD0113 can you post how you built it?